# Is there a Java equivalent of Python's printf hash replacement?

Tags: java, python

Specifically I am converting a python script into a java helper method. Here is a snippet (slightly modified for simplicity).

```
# hash of values
vals = {}
vals['a'] = 'a'
vals['b'] = 'b'
vals['1'] = 1

output = sys.stdout
file = open(filename).read()

print >>output, file % vals,
```

So in the file there are %(a), %(b), %(1) etc that I want substituted with the hash keys. I perused the API but couldn't find anything. Did I miss it or does something like this not exist in the Java API?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @Dana: Doesn't matter. Any from the last few versions supports this.

Comment: True, but for str.format(), I've come across lots of cases where py ver < 2.6

Comment: This is part of string interpolation, not `str.format()`.

Comment: But I am converting to Java. The python script works today as is and is running in production. So it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you'll find a pure Java solution that'll do exactly what you want out of the box.

With this in mind, the best answer depends on the complexity and variety of Python formatting strings that appear in your file:

- If they're simple and not varied, the easiest way might be to code something up yourself.
- If the opposite is true, one way to get the result you want with little work is by [embedding Jython into your Java program](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/embedding.html). This will enable you to use Python's string formatting operator (`%`) directly. What's more, you'll be able to give it a Java `Map` as if it were a Python dictionary (`vals` in your code).

Comment: The first statement is true. Therefore I did not wish to import another library or anything. We have an existing Java application that would simply inform an external system to run the script. Instead we are just importing the script into the system to remove dependencies. I was able to write a static format method to use a HashMap with unit tests probably much faster than using any external solution :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly without some additional templating library. I recommend [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/). Very lightweight, [easy to use](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Five+minute+Introduction), and very optimized and robust.

Comment: Looks like a nice library, I will keep this in my records for future projects. This however is a relatively simple re-implementation so I will just code something myself.